# Duplicate Tag accepted by JAXB

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb, unmarshalling

In our application, User is sending an XML like below:

```html
<Decl>
  <MessageHeader>
     <A>Info</A>
     <B>Info2</B>
  </MessageHeader>
</Decl>
```

and using JABX unmarshller we are populating the java object.
But the problem is customer is asking to generate the error when he/she
send the message like below:

```html
<Decl>
  <MessageHeader>
     <A>Info</A>
     <B>Info2</B>
  </MessageHeader>
<MessageHeader>
     <A>Info3</A>
     <B>Info4</B>
  </MessageHeader>
</Decl>
```

JAXB is successfully unmarshling the xml and populating the object with second MessageHeader Object. Please note MessageHeader is not List type.
Is there any way to stop JAXB to behave like this and it should throw ParsingException. We cannot use schema validation of xml before parsing due to some reason. But is there any way that we can instruct JAXB parser to check target type is list or not and throw the error.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

JAXB is a technology for generating Java classes for an XML Schema model. Therefore, any validation that JAXB performs is going to use XML Schema validation.

> Is there any way to stop JAXB to behave like this and it should throw ParsingException

No. Not unless you enable schema validation in your JAXB unmarshaller.

> We cannot use schema validation of xml before parsing due to some reason.

You should either supply the reason, or not mention it. It's a very strange rule, given that JAXB is an XML Schema technology and Java has native support for XSD validation.

> Please note MessageHeader is not List type.

A List type is for *simple* types. MessageHeader is based on a complex type.

I recommend that you ignore the rule that says 'no schema validation'. Set maxOccurs=1 on MessageHeader and enable schema validation on the JAXB unmarshaller.

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out, the way to go is to use schema validation. Generate a schema and set maxOccurs="1" on MessageHeader. You can set the schema with:

```
unmarshaller.setSchema(schema);
```

If for some strange reason you absolutely cannot use schema validation you could do an ugly hack to throw an exception when a duplicated MessageHeader is processed with an implementation of `Unmarshaller.Listener`

```
unmarshaller.setListener(new Unmarshaller.Listener() {

    boolean messageHeaderAlreadyPresent = false;

    @Override
    public void beforeUnmarshal(Object target, Object parent) {
        // When <Decl> is encountered, set to false
        if (target instanceof Decl) {
            messageHeaderAlreadyPresent = false;
        } else if (target instanceof MessageHeader) {
            if (messageHeaderAlreadyPresent) {
                throw new RuntimeException("duplicate MessageHeader");
            }
            messageHeaderAlreadyPresent = true;
        }
    }
});
```

Although this should work, I insist that you should reconsider schema validation.

Also note that the unmarshaller silently ignores some events, for example when encounters en element that is not mapped. That's not your case, because there is no mapping problem in your use case, but, for example if you received the message:

```
<Decl>
  <MessageHeader>
     <A>Info1</A>
     <C>Info3</C>
  </MessageHeader>
</Decl>
```

with element `<C>` instead of `<B>`, you would end up with values A = Info1 and B = null, as JAXB would silently ignore the element `<C>`.

You can capture these events and throw an exception setting a `ValidationEventHandler` to return `false`

```
unmarshaller.setEventHandler(new ValidationEventHandler() {
    @Override
    public boolean handleEvent(ValidationEvent event) {
        // log event ....
        return false;
    }
});
```